# XSD: XSL stylesheet child element warnings in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt, xsd

I have an XSD defined for a messaging application. As part of the message payload, I need to require that, for one of my elements, the content be an XSL stylesheet. This is used later in applying an XSL transformation to generate the final formatted output. Please note that the payload of the XSL stylesheet is an end-user decision, thus I cannot simply make an XSD to validate its contents. Ideally, it would be great if there was an XSD for HTML, because I would simply use that as the namespace for the non-XSL content in the stylesheet!

Thus, I did this (this is only part of the XSD, but you get the ideas):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.mycorpname.com/notification"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns="http://schemas.mycorpname.com/notification">

        <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" />
        <xs:complexType name="renderinginstructions">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="xsl:stylesheet"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This works great, and forces the consumers to include an XSL stylesheet inside the `<renderinginstructions>` element.

Most of the time, the XSL stylesheet should include tags to output a valid HTML document. However, when I place child elements into the stylesheet definition, I get this error from Visual Studio:

[image]

If I want to require the presence of an embedded XSL stylesheet (and not any other content!), did I create my XSD properly? What else can I do? I don't like this warning.

Here is an example of the type of document that induces this warning.

**NOTE: In the stylesheet, if I use xmlns="", I get the warning only. If I don't specify a default namespace, I do not get the warning, but I get a "Message" from Visual Studio stating:**

> "Could not find schema information for the element
>   'http://schemas.mycorpname.com/notification:html'".

**So, with `xmlns=""`, I get a Warning. Without it, I get tons of "Messages", all related to the child elements of xsl:template. Isn't the very purpose of XSLT to be able to put tons of various elements in the document? Are XSLT not subject to schema validation when they stand alone?**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<notification xmlns="http://schemas.mycorpname.com/notification">
    <renderinginstructions>
         <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="">
                    <xsl:template match="/">
                        <html>
                            <head>This is the head</head>
                            <body>This is the body.</body>
                        </html>
                    </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
    </renderinginstructions>
</notification>
```

Comment: Tricky one.. have you tried putting the html namespace instead of xmlns="" in your `xsl:stylesheet` element?

Comment: This is a great idea, and I looked into this, but I cannot find an XSD for HTML! If you know the URI, I will definitely add it and give this a shot!

Comment: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` I think you can actually find this just by creating a new html document in VS, it'll probably be at the top by default.

Comment: This looks like the XHTML namespace. Will that work?

Comment: Sure. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/namespaces.html

Comment: This brings more hate from the parser. Now it complains about all of the xsl: elements, as being invalid child elements of the elements in the "html" namespace. So, for example, if I have an "<xsl:value-of" inside of an <html:p></html:p>, it complains that I cannot have the invalid child element "<xsl:value-of" inside of "html:p". This is looking like I will just have to deal with the "Warning" from Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, you could just have your HTML elements generated with `<xsl:element name="html">..</xsl:element>` instead of `<html>..</html>`, but it's a tad more verbose, and that does kind of feel like giving up on doing it properly. That kind of frustration's par for the course with VS though.

Comment: That's a cool idea, although you're right: it feels like giving up. That gave me a laugh for the day. I'll award you checkmark if you make an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update this: I ended up just dealing with the warning.